# Jsonpath syntax to extract specific parent keys with specific child keys

Tags: json, jsonpath

Is it possible to filter json by jsonpath query to get specific keys of parents AND specific keys of childs?

Here is the json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "paymentProviders": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "supported": true, 
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "fields": [],
                        "key": "paypal",
                        "maintenance": false,
                        "settings": [
                            {
                                "max": 10000,
                                "min": 100
                            }
                        ],
                        "withdrawalFields": []
                    },
                    {
                        "fields": [],
                        "key": "moneta",
                        "maintenance": false,
                        "settings": [
                            {
                                "key": "deposits",
                                "max": 10000,
                                "min": 100
                            }
                        ],
                        "withdrawalFields": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "currency": "GBP",
                "supported": true, 
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "fields": [],
                        "key": "directTransfer",
                        "maintenance": false,
                        "settings": [
                            {
                                "key": "deposits",
                                "max": 0,
                                "min": 100
                            }
                        ],
                        "withdrawalFields": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "supported": true, 
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "fields": [],
                        "key": "paypal",
                        "maintenance": false,
                        "settings": [
                            {
                                "key": "deposits",
                                "max": 10000,
                                "min": 100
                            }
                        ],
                        "withdrawalFields": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get only 'currency', 'providers.key' and 'providers.maintenance' from it, like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "paymentProviders": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "key": "paypal",
                        "maintenance": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "moneta",
                        "maintenance": false,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "currency": "GBP",
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "key": "directTransfer",
                        "maintenance": false,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "key": "paypal",
                        "maintenance": false,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I use something like

> $..['key', 'maintenance']

I'll lose that 'currency' property.

Basically, I want to use 'Union operator' pattern inside another 'Union operator' pattern, idea is this:

> $..["currency","providers.['key', 'maintenance']"]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$..['currency','key','maintenance']
```

You should get

```
[
    "USD",
    "paypal",
    false,
    "moneta",
    false,
    "deposits",
    "GBP",
    "directTransfer",
    false,
    "deposits",
    "EUR",
    "paypal",
    false,
    "deposits"
]
```

Compare with [Goessner](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)

Note that the jsonpath union operator will only give you a list of values, without the contextual elements that you have in your desired results.